# Where can I find or create a urllist.txt file?

Tags: php, file, search-engine

I'm trying to make a simple search engine, just to know how it works. I'm following an old tutorial on how to do it with php and mySQL.

However it doesn't explain how to create a urllist.txt file. I downloaded a Quantcast-Top-Million.txt file as required but i'm still confused about how to create a urllist and how it's related to the Quantcast-Top-Million.txt file.

```
$file_handle = fopen("Quantcast-Top-Million.txt", 
"r");

while (!feof ($file_handle)){
    $line=fgets($file_handle);
    if(preg_match('/ˆ\d+/',$line)){
        $tmp=explode("\t",$line);
        $rank=trim($tmp[0]);
        $url=trim($tmp[1]);
        if($url != 'Hidden profile') {
            echo $i ;
        }
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);


$file_handle = fopen("urllist.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $url = trim(fgets($file_handle));
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $document = array($url,$content);
    $serialized = serialize($document);
    $fp = fopen('./documents/'.md5($url), 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $serialized); fclose($fp);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Actually what you are trying? Are you trying to fetch all urls from "Quantcast-Top-Million.txt" & write to a new file

Comment: I don't know. The tutorial I'm using didn't say how the two files are related, just that they are both needed for the search engine to work.